# javascript: mapping same and different key to different values

Tags: javascript

```
var dict = {
'thunder':    'severe thunderstorms',
     'sun':    'thunderstorms',
     'moon':    'mixed rain and snow',
 'Rain':    'severe thunderstorms',
     'Rain':    'thunderstorms',
     'Rain':    'mixed rain and snow',
     'Rain':    'mixed rain and sleet',
}
var result = String(state.cell.value.key);

/*How do I get 
     sun
   /     \
thunder weather
           \
           rain
              |- 'severe thunderstorms'
              |- 'thunderstorms'
              |- 'mixed rain and snow'
              |- 'mixed rain and sleet'*/
```

Comment: Vio, you cannot have an object with the same propertyName multiple times. So you're approaching an unapproachable problem :)

Comment: However what you can do is having an array as your object field :
  `'Rain':    ['thunderstorms','mixed rain and snow','mixed rain and sleet']`

Answer (score 1):

Just use an [array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp):

```
var dict = {
    thunder: 'severe thunderstorms',
    sun: 'thunderstorms',
    moon: 'mixed rain and snow',
    rain: ['severe thunderstorms',
        'thunderstorms',
        'mixed rain and snow',
        'mixed rain and sleet']
}
console.log(dict)
```

Comment: var writeKey= String(state.cell.value.dept);
    var writeValue=String(state.cell.value.name);
     
    var myMap = new Map();
     myMap.set(writeKey,writeValue);
     if( myMap.has(writeKey)){
      //stuck here now
     }

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit more? :)

Comment: Currently I recieve the data in the format:

 'thunder':    'severe thunderstorms',
 'sun':    'thunderstorms',
 'moon':    'mixed rain and snow',
 'Rain':    'severe thunderstorms',
 'Rain':    'thunderstorms',
 'Rain':    'mixed rain and snow',
 'Rain':    'mixed rain and sleet'

But the format want to achieve is this:
 
 thunder: 'severe thunderstorms',
    sun: 'thunderstorms',
    moon: 'mixed rain and snow',
    rain: ['severe thunderstorms',
        'thunderstorms',
        'mixed rain and snow',
        'mixed rain and sleet']

and build a tree above

Comment: Ok but I guess you get a string with the content you mention because as @Roko C. Buljan said you cannot have an object with the same propertyName multiple times, is that correct?